# Use gradle to build front-end in Spring Boot

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, gradle

I have the following setup in my fullstack Spring boot + thymeleaf + react

The project structure look like this

`build.gradle
|src
  |main
    |java
    |resources
      index.js
      package.json
      build.gradle`

I use a gradle script under resources folder to build front end SPA.
the script look like this

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.2.0"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

task build(type: YarnTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}
build.dependsOn('yarn_install')
task deleteModules(type: Delete) {
    delete "node_modules"
}
deleteModules.dependsOn('build')
```

The above build will build a SPA with `index.html` and `index.js`

My question is, how do I include this in the top level build.gradle. So that every time the java application is getting build, it will build the front-end SPA first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better to put the build of the frontend in the main `build.gradle` file.

e.g. something like

```
apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

task buildFrontend(type: YarnTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
}
tasks.build.dependsOn buildFrontend
```

Comment: Ended up putting all the build in the main gradle file. Configuring path for gradle.node is very confusing though